# Continuity of the flow of a continuous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\dot x = f(t,x)$ be a differential equation where $f:\Omega \to R^n$ is continuous and in a such a way that every IWP $\dot x = f(t,x), x(t_0) = x_0$ has a unique maximal solution. Is the flow $\Phi(t,t_0,x_0)$ continuous and is its domain open?

$\Phi(\cdot,t_0,x_0)$ descripes the unique solution of the above IWP defined on its maximal intervall of existence.

Simular statements are usually proven under the assumption that f is in addition locally-lipschitz-continuous in $x$ (and then we obtain local-lipschitz-continuity in $x_0$ for $\Phi(t,t_0,x_0)$), but does it hold under the given assumptions?

I wasn't able to proove the statement nor do i know a counterexample, thank you for helping me :)